# Laravel Eloquent query building for serching by year of a date

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am a beginner at laravel and I am working in implementing a search.

there is a row of date and I need to search by year, I read and tried a couple of solutions but I could not find a good solution.

this is the query i found in internet as a potential solution but this is not working:

```
$Data = DB::table('actuals')->where('company_id',$companyId)->whereYear('date', '=', $SearchInput)->orderBy('date', 'asc')->get();
```

Comment: Do you have a model for `actuals` e.g. `Actual`?

Comment: yes i do, i just decided to work with tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
$Data = DB::table('actuals')->where(function($nest) use($SearchInput,$companyId) {
    $nest->where('company_id',$companyId);
    $nest->whereYear('date', '=', $SearchInput); 
})->orderBy('date', 'asc')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your `$searchInput` is full date like `d-m-Y`, try converting it to year:

```
    $searchYr = date('Y',strtotime($searchInput));
    $Data = DB::table('actuals')->where('company_id',$companyId)->whereYear('date', '=', $searchYr)->orderBy('date', 'asc')->get();
```

Hope it will work.

Comment: this is not resolving the problem, still no result

Comment: Can you post sample table row from your table.

Comment: do you need a row of the table from db

Comment: Yes along with column names.

Comment: INSERT INTO `actuals`(`id`, `account_level_l`, `account_level_ll`, `account_level_lll`, `date`, `type`, `num`, `name`, `class`, `description`, `split`, `amount`, `company_id`) VALUES ([value-1],[value-2],[value-3],[value-4],[value-5],[value-6],[value-7],[value-8],[value-9],[value-10],[value-11],[value-12],[value-13])

Comment: https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-53-wheredate-wheremonth-whereday-and-whereyear-examplesexample.html

Comment: Just check what are you passing in $companyId and $searchInput. Try removing rest of condition and orderBy clause.

Answer (score 0):

With Eloquent it would be something like this :

```
Actual::orderBy("date", "ASC")->where("company_id, $companyId)->where("date","LIKE", $searchInput."%")->get();
```